# How do I run Chrome extension content script after a site's javascript has finished building page?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, content-script, page-load-time

I know that I can use run_at: document end to run a script after a page is loaded, but most sites now inject most of their content through some kind of js framework. From what I can tell the content.js script is running before those can finish.

I have some ideas on how to do this, but I'm not really if they really make sense, or even how to do them if they did.

1. Run my script every time the DOM updates so that if a hyperlink is added I can just remove the hrefs again.

   I found this [domwatcher thing in uBlock origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/blob/master/src/js/contentscript.js#L179), I assume he's doing something like this in order to remove any ads that show up, but it's really complex and I'm not sure what things I would or wouldn't need.
2. Run the extension every second or two. This seems really clumsy, but maybe it's a standard thing? I'm not sure. I also don't know how I would get a content script to repeat, something this simple couldn't cause performance issues right?
3. Javascript scripts are executed in order when they are listed in html right? So maybe I add the script to the end of all those? But they run asynchronously anyway right so that probably wouldn't work. Either way, some way to run my script after all the others are done. Can I put them in promises?

Also here is my [GitHub page with all the code](https://github.com/draav/remove-hyperlink-hrefs).

The relevant manifest:

```
 "content_scripts": [
    {
    "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
        ],
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
    }
]
```

And content.js:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('isEnabled', function (data) {
    if(!data.isEnabled) {
        return;
    }

    for (let link of document.links) {
        link.removeAttribute('href');
        console.log(link);
    }
});
```

Comment: if there's *some script* that dynamically adds *stuff* to the DOM, then the only real solution is to watch for changes on the DOM - as for your very last statement, Promises wont help, as they do not change the (a)synchrony of code - in fact, Promises are by nature asynchronous

Comment: MutationObserver.

Comment: The last one is me reaching lol, I couldn't think of any way that I could tell if those other scripts were done touching stuff and inserting elements.

Comment: @wOxxOm yeah I saw this [blog post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/) on Mutation observer, and tried adding this code to my content.js, but it never seemed to log anything so I assumed it wouldn't work.

code:
`    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {`
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            console.log(mutation.type);
        });
    });
    var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true }
`    observer.observe(document, config);`

Comment: the config should have subtree:true, otherwise it won't log anything since `document` root node isn't modified.

Comment: @wOxxOm I haven't heard anything about subtree:true, so thanks for that tip I'll research what that is and how to include it

Answer (score 1):

Since the DOM is dynamically generated by whatever frameworks/libraries it is using, I would watch for any changes in the DOM and process the newly created content instead. I think this would work better than trying to detect when the DOM content has finished building and run `contentScripts` anyway, considering a page content can be dynamically generated and changed anytime when a user is on the page.

My solution is that you could watch for any newly created link elements and remove `href` attribute if it matches your desired pattern. This can be done by using either of these:

- [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver): A Javascript interface for watching changes in the DOM
- [Arrive.js](https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive): a library for watching changes in the DOM.

The **uBlock** example you provided also uses `MutationObserver` to watch for changes of the DOM tree, so I think the author is also using the methodology I've mentioned here.

Comment: Coll that makes sense to me. Are you aware of any simple examples or tutorials that talk about how to integrate MutationObserver into content scripts. Do they go into the content script or some other kind of script like background or something.

Comment: I practiced MutationObserver before on [David Walsh's blog](https://davidwalsh.name/mutationobserver-api). I don't know any examples of it running in a contentScripts though. But I have tried before in my Chrome extension and it's just as straightforward.